# Restful Authentication plugin and Users model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I have a question about using the restful-authentication plugin. I have it working just fine with the "out of the box" setup.

I am trying to add a user partial form nested into a form of another model. I can not seem to figure out how to have this form add a new user to the users model. I have other nested forms that work just fine.

I think the problem is that the user model does not have a user_controller but instead is supposed to use :url => user_profiles_path so when I nest this in another form it doesn't work.

I am just so lost, I need to figure out how to nest a new User form into a Unit/new form.

I am not sure if this makes sense, but any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're working with a legacy application, try using [**AuthLogic**](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) for authentication instead...it'll save you a lot of headaches!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am pretty new to rails and built a small app around restful-authentication already, do you think it is difficult to scratch that and change to authlogic?

Comment: Unless you are following a book or some sort of tutorial, I would just start from scratch. Follow this great video tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic